# Do the comment boxes no-longer auto-focus?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

Is it just me, or does the comment input field no longer automatically gain focus when I hit "add comment"? I never realised I used it, but now that it's gone it's really annoying me!

<sub>Firefox 25.0.1 on Windows XP SP3</sub>

Comment: I typed out a long comment response, but didn't notice the comment box was not focused, so I gave up and just posted this, instead ;)

Comment: Same version but on linux 64bits, and also have to clic before typing comment. I didn't know if it was or was not the case before.

Comment: Yay, fixed! :-)