# Change in comment box activation?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

I just noticed today that if I click on "add comment" my cursor doesn't automatically jump to the newly opened comment box - I have to make a second click before I start typing. I think this just started happening today.

Comment: @Oded Should [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208919/241700) also be marked as completed?

Comment: @qwertynl - yep. Thanks. Missed that dupe.

Comment: No prob @Oded :-D